# Why is awstats reporting my static IP instead of Domain Name?

Tags: ssrs, reporting, reverse-dns, static-ip, awstats

In AWStats under: "Links from an external page (other web sites except search engines)" it has generated a list of pages that had linked to my page. I see pages like: Bing, YouTube, HotFrog, etc.. However, there are many internal links within the pages. Towards the bottom it is reporting as followed:

```
http://72.249.150.9/distributors.php           5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/contact/                   5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/catalog/                   4     1.9 %
http://72.249.150.9/flex-point-hockey-grip.php 5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/sticky-grip-foam.php       5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/video.php                 10     4.8 %
http://72.249.150.9/dealers/                   5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/feedback/                  5     2.4 %
http://72.249.150.9/products.php              10     4.8 %
http://72.249.150.9/ergo-hockey-grip.php       5     2.4 %
```

**Note**: Static IP was set in place because of the SSL requirement.

Comment: Could it be that my client is referencing the whole URL to his pages in his navigation?
i.e: http://www.website.com/products.html vs products.html

Answer (score 2):

Because your site is also being visited by it's IP-address (without your domainname). AWStats doesn't know this is the same website unless you configure the HostAliases configuration directive. Add this to your AWStats configuration:

```
HostAliases="72.249.150.9"
```

Another solution would be redirecting visitors who visit your website by it's IP-address to your domainname (I would recommend this anyway). You can do this with mod_write and a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*?your.domain$ [NC]
ReWriteRule /(.*)$ http://www.your.domain/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I went to my awstats.conf file and found the following

HostAliases="www.oggiegrip.com oggiegrip.com"

Would it be bad to overwrite this with what you suggested? Or should I just go the .HTACCESS route?

Comment: Add the IP address to the existing `HostAliases` separated by a space. And check the .htaccess, people are visiting your site by it's IP address, you don't want that ;).

Comment: When adding to the HostAliases file do I need to recompile a .pl file?

Comment: Also, I see the rewrite Condition you advised but I tried that and it failed to work.

Instead I'm using:

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /  
      
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oggiegrip.com  
    ReWriteRule (.*) http://www.oggiegrip.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: You don't need to recompile AWStats after altering the configuration, just let AWStats analyze your logfiles. Not sure if AWStats will remove the existing IP Address from the list of sites linking to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[johnathan@VM:~] $ host 72.249.150.9
Host 9.150.249.72.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

You need to setup reverse DNS for that IP so that your web server can map the IP back to a domain name. Your ISP can normally help you with this, alternatively, if you're running the server from your home IP look into something like the Free services offered by dyndns.org.

```
[johnathan@VM:~] $ host 109.xxx.xxx.131
131.26.169.109.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer starscream.xxxxxxxxx.com.
[johnathan@VM:~] $ host starscream.xxxxxxxxx.com
starscream.xxxxxxxxx.com has address 109.xxx.xxx.131
```

That's the sort of return you should get ... just for reference.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not running this from home. Is it only possible to create a reverse DNS by contacting the ISP?

Comment: Also, what are you running to use that host command?  
I tried SSH'ing to a *nix box but was unable to use that.

Comment: apparently the Linux box I was on didn't have that command so I ssh'd to another server.

Comment: Referring sites has nothing to do with reverse DNS. @Austin: your .htaccess doesn't work yet. You'll have to forward http://72.249.150.9/ to your domain.

Comment: @PowerSp00n, seems to be working fine on my end. When I try oggiegrip.com it immediately adds the www. prefix.

Comment: The IP address is your problem, not the domain itself. Try to visit it and see for yourself. You'll have to make sure your website is only accessible via your primary domain and forward all the others (including IP addresses).